# Change Fontawesome icon in Nativescript Vue

Tags: css, vue.js, nativescript, font-awesome

I'm creating a voting system. For both positive and negative votes, i use the same component - VoteButton. How to change the icon ( 'fa-thumbs-o-up' to 'fa-thumbs-up' and 'fa-thumbs-o-down' to 'fa-thumbs-down') when the button is activated? Which is the best option - via CSS (:before), vue.js logic ( IF or something), replace string via JS or something else?

Parent component:

```
<GridLayout columns="auto,*">
   <VoteButton col="0" :buttontext=" 'fa-thumbs-o-up' | fonticon"  :votes="upVotes" label="Upvote" :active="upvoted" width="33%" @click="vote(1)" />
   <VoteButton col="1" :buttontext=" 'fa-thumbs-o-down' | fonticon" :votes="downVotes" label="Downvote" :active="downvoted" width="33%" @click="vote(-1)" />
</GridLayout>
```

Parent component CSS:

```
.upvote.active {
        background: orangered;
        color: white;
 }

.downvote.active {
        background: blue;
        color: white;
 }
```

VoteButton child component:

```
<template>
  <button @tap="$emit('click')" :class="[buttonClass, { active }]">
    <FormattedString>
        <Span class="fa" > {{ buttontext }}</Span>
        <Span> {{ votes }}</Span>            
    </FormattedString>
  </button>  
</template>

<script>

export default {
    props: {
        active: Boolean,
        label: String,
        buttontext: String,
        votes: Number
    },

  computed: {
    buttonClass() {
      return this.label.toLowerCase();
    }
  }

};
</script>
```

Comment: There is never one best option, but here I would suggest applying different class name in your binding when the button is activated Or pass the activated button text upfront and use it based on activated flag within component.

Comment: I think I did it at your suggestion. It works! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could use a counter in javascript to keep track of whether the button should be displaying an upvote or a downvote based on the number of times the button is pressed.

Example:

Html:

```
<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<div id="myDIV">
This is a DIV element.
</div>
```

CSS:

```
<style>
.mystyle {
 background: orangered;
 color: white;
 }
 .mystyle2 {
 background: blue;
 color: white;
 }
 </style>
```

Javascript:

```
<script>
var x = 0;
function myFunction() {
var element = document.getElementById("myDIV");
if (x % 2 == 0){
element.classList.add("mystyle");
element.classList.remove("mystyle2");
x++; 
}
else {
element.classList.add("mystyle2");
element.classList.remove("mystyle");
x++;
}
}
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks! I have a DB and Laravel as API backend, so I get from there voted status.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks! I did it the following way:

Parent:

```
<VoteButton col="0" noactivefatext='fa-thumbs-o-up' activefatext='fa-thumbs-up' :votes="upVotes" label="Upvote" :active="upvoted" @click="vote(1)" />
<VoteButton col="1" noactivefatext='fa-thumbs-o-down' activefatext='fa-thumbs-down' :votes="downVotes" label="Downvote" :active="downvoted" @click="vote(-1)" />
```

VoteButton component:

```
<template>
  <button @tap="$emit('click')" :class="[buttonClass, { active }]">
    <FormattedString>
      <Span class="fa body" :text="active ? activefatext : noactivefatext | fonticon" ></Span>
      <Span> {{ votes }}</Span>            
    </FormattedString>
  </button>  
</template>
```